# Current Version is: OS X el Capitan 10.11.6 What's Next?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, upgrade

I am using MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) the problem is I can't see any update to newer version on App Store! Can anyone here send me the link to update online or download updates to next version.. I am very new user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Answer (score 2):

The highest version of macOS you might be able to run is High Sierra - why not download that installer or try sierra?

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208202
- http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-39476-20191023-48f365f4-0015-4c41-9f44-39d3d2aca067/InstallOS.dmg

As commented - we have several questions on how to download specific versions if that’s the thing that’s blocking you.

- [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/)